# Throttle Geometry in OpenGL (OpenTK)

Tags: c#, opengl, rendering, minecraft, opentk

I've been working on a client for Minecraft Classic in C# using the OpenTK library (OpenGL) and I have a problem.

When the client receives a SetBlock packet, it will draw the block in the same way as when you place a block, but when a cuboid happens (1 block every 150ms), the client lags because it is receiving too many tile updates per second (sometimes to the point of being unresponsive) and some faces are not drawn at all.

Ive searched everywhere for the problem, but cannot find it. I was wondering if throttling the geometry per "tick" would resolve the issue? How can I do that?

Also, if you have any suggestions on what could be the cause, please let me know!

Here is the source code, if you need it all all.

https://github.com/GlennMR/800Craft-Client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [culling](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/clipping.htm) the inner faces of the blocks to improve performance or use [common voxel rendering optimization techniques](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/minecraft-voxel-performance/26097/view.html).